# PowerShell ISE - Rename File Add String

Tags: powershell

I try to get the first 5 numbers from a file name with PowerShell , for example, I have this pdf doc. "43236_1_REMESA_COPY_TRANS.pdf"

This is my code to rename the file:

```
Get-ChildItem $workfile -Filter "*_REMESA_PRIMERA_COPIA__TRANSPORTISTA.pdf" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + '_REM_REMESA.pdf.tsk'}
```

(`Directory.Name` take the folder name, in this case the folder name is "92B0336679")

I have this result "92B0336679_REM_REMESA.pdf.tsk", but i can't add the first 5 numbers from the original file.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest piping to `ForEach-Object { $Prefix = $_.Name.Substring(0,5) }`

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps or gets you on track

```
Get-ChildItem $workfile -Filter "*.pdf" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {"$((((gi $workfile).Name).ToCharArray() | select -First 5) -join '')$($_.Directory.Name)_REM_REMESA.pdf.tsk"}
```

Comment: Thanks Thom, I Forgot one thing, in workfile I have one o more folders, depending of how many folders the user places, and those folders are named "43236","43237",etc, I need this number before ".pdf.tsk", ex. "92B0336679_REM_REMESA43236.pdf.tsk"